# streamでリストの結合がしたい

Tags: java, java8, stream

[[a, a, a], [b, b, b], [c, c, c]]
を
[a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c]
こうしたいのですが、streamで一発で出来る方法ってありますか？

```
//普通にループするとこんな感じです。
List innerA = Arrays.asList("a","a","a");
List innerB = Arrays.asList("b","b","b");
List innerC = Arrays.asList("c","c","c");
List<List> outer = Arrays.asList(innerA,innerB,innerC);
System.out.println(outer);
//[[a, a, a], [b, b, b], [c, c, c]]

List innerABC = new ArrayList<>();
for(List inner : outer){
    innerABC.addAll(inner);
}
System.out.println(innerABC);
//[a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c]
```

Answer (score 4):

[Stream#flatMap(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)が使えるかもしれません。

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class StreamTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> innerA = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "a");
    List<String> innerB = Arrays.asList("b", "b", "b");
    List<String> innerC = Arrays.asList("c", "c", "c");
    List<List<String>> outer = Arrays.asList(innerA, innerB, innerC);
    //List innerABC = new ArrayList<>();
    //for(List inner : outer){
    //    innerABC.addAll(inner);
    //}
    List<String> innerABC = outer.stream()
      .flatMap(lst -> lst.stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(innerABC);
  }
}
```

Comment: できました！
flatMap(lst -> lst.stream())
ここでstreame自体を返す発想が思いつきませんでした。。。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと変わった方法ですがこんなのもどうですか？

```
Optional<List<String>> innerABC = outer.stream()
    .reduce((s1, s2) -> concat(s1.stream(), s2.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
if(innerABC.isPresent()){
   System.out.println(innerABC.get());
}
```